# ASP.NET MVC application cookie not posted in Request in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies

[image]I have a site developed in ASP.NET MVC 3.0, the login page has language selection dropdown to support localization. Once the drop down get the new value with the help of javascript I am setting a cookie value for the new language selected, and refresh the page with location.reload(). But I checked in the IE debug tools the request does not have the cookie value. However, in Chrome and Mozilla it is working as expected. I cannot able to debug in my local as in my local code in IE browser as well it is working fine. Only issue is when deployed it is not working only in IE browser.

```
   $("#Language").change(function () {
        var lang = $('#Language').find(":selected").val();
        alert('language: ' + lang);
        createCookie("myCookie", lang,1);
        location.reload();
    });
   function createCookie(name, value, days) {
        var expires = "";
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
        }
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }
```

C#:

```
        var cookie = Request.Cookies["MyCookie"];
        if (cookie != null)
            cookieValue = cookie.Value;
```

Problem is with the cookie. The following cookie value that i got in Local
Key                Value
cookie1                Token=
cookie2                Refresh=
ASP.NET_SessionId      iijh3fbbh3qwge0l5gq33u13
userLangChoice         es
cookie6 Token=
cookie7 Refresh=

But userLangChoice cookie not present in the deployed site.

Comment: Did you notice any error or warning message in the console of IE? If yes than let us know about that. try to put the console.log in every function and than try to host your code to make a test with IE. Check every JS function executes properly and logging the message in console. Also try to set some label on UI from your server side code to confirm that it is also executing correctly. It can help to find the problematic code. Also try to check that cookies are allowed in your IE browser. Let us know about your testing results. We will try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: One warning: DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337

Comment: For this warning, Try to replace location.reload(); with window.location.href. Let us know about the other testing results using console.log. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: As I checked the cookie value has not been sent in the request, the cookie has been handled for the new language and the back ground code getting it as null. So it is processing as default language that is en-Us (internal code logic)

Comment: Please see my post I edited something. The problem is with the cookie "userLangChoice" that is absent in the request.

Comment: Try to access your site from any other machine using IE 11 to check whether issue is producible on any IE browser.